# Поиск корневой директории в строке

Tags: php

Есть строки:

1. /home/i/p/S/var/DR/IN/m/1;**/home/i/p/DIRS/var/DR/IN/D/1**;/home/i/p/S/var/DR/IN/m/4;
2. /home/i/p/SU/var/DR/I/s/1;/home/i/p/SU/var/DR/I/s/3;/home/i/p/SU/var/DR/I/s/5;

Нужно найти строки у которых общий корень — общая директория и оставить только общий корень (из 1 строки оставить только `/home/i/p/S/var/DR/IN/m` из 2 сроки оставить только `/home/i/p/SU/var/DR/I/s` и т.д. со всеми строками). При этом некоторые директории могут этот общий корень не иметь.

Сравнивать все строки через `preg_match` мне кажется как-то не эффективно. Может есть более красивое решение?

Comment: А что если строка вида `/корень1/ф1;/корень2/ф2;/корень1/ф3;/корень2/ф4;` т.е. в строке присутствуют 2 корня, встречающиеся более чем у одного элемента, какой из корней считать общим для всей строки ?

Comment: Считаем в таком случае: /корень1/  ;  /корень2/

Comment: Я пока не могу понять как определять этот корень. Перебирать все и сравнивать друг с другом совсем не хочется.

Comment: Это можно сделать одной регуляркой. по крайней мере она сможет дать корни, которые встречаются более 1 раза. либо проверить, что вся строка целиком состоит из одинаковых корней. И вот тут вопрос, что же именно вам надо ...

Comment: Например что то в этом роде https://regex101.com/r/1RcGeu/1 Оно может найти не все множественные корни, если их несколько, но один точно даст, если он конечно есть

Comment: @DimaKuzmin Так для первой строки у вас должен быть общий корень `/home/i/p` а не `/home/i/p/S/var/DR/IN/m`, так как различия на 4-м уровне

Answer (score 1):

Mожет функциями `explode` и `implode` решить вопрос, разделить строки на знак `/`, потом сново собрать?

```
$str = '/home/i/p/SU/var/DR/I/s/1';
$tmp_arr = explode('/',$str);
unset($tmp_arr[count($tmp_arr)-1]); убираем последний элемент массива.
$str = implode('/',$tmp_arr);
```

Comment: А если у нас один из путей в строке будет отличаться? например: /home/i/p/SU/var/DR/I/s/1;/home/i/p/SU/var/DR/I/s/3;/home/i/p/SU/var/DIRS/I/ASD/33;

Comment: @DimaKuzmin значит нужно задать вопрос корректно, что бы и ответ был под все ваши нужды.

Answer (score 1):

```
$tests['/home/i/p/S/var/DR/IN/m/1;/home/i/p/DIRS/var/DR/IN/D/1;/home/i/p/S/var/DR/IN/m/4;'] = '/home/i/p';
$tests['/home/i/p/SU/var/DR/I/s/1;/home/i/p/SU/var/DR/I/s/3;/home/i/p/SU/var/DR/I/s/5;'] = '/home/i/p/SU/var/DR/I/s';
$tests['/home/i/p/SU/var/DR/I/s/1;/home/i/p/SU/var/DR/I/s/3;/home/i/p/SU/var/DIRS/I/ASD/33;'] = '/home/i/p/SU/var';

foreach ($tests as $rule => $result) {
    $paths = explode(';', $rule);
    $tree = [];
    $flatResult = [];

    foreach ($paths as $path) {
        $path = trim($path);

        if (empty($path)) {
            continue;
        }

        $arr = &$tree;
        $names = explode('/', $path);

        foreach ($names as $name) {
            if (empty($name)) {
                continue;
            }

            $arr = &$arr[$name];
        }

        $arr = null;
    }

    while ($key = key($tree)) {
        $flatResult[] = $key;

        if (count($tree[$key]) > 1) {
            break;
        }

        $tree = $tree[$key];
    }

    $flatResult = "/" . implode('/', $flatResult);

    if ($flatResult !== $result) {
        throw new Exception('Invalid scenario');
    }

    echo "{$flatResult}\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте [развить](http://ideone.com/N4XpOb)

```
// делим строку по точке с запятой

$stringMain = "/home/i/p/S/var/DR/IN/m/1;/home/i/p/S/var/DR/IN/m/2;/home/i/p/S/var/DR/IN/m/4;";
$piecesMain = explode(";", $stringMain);
$compare = []; //создаем пустой массив для сравнения

for ($i = 0; $i < count($piecesMain[0]); $i++)
    { //создаем массив сначала из первого элемента массива
    $pieces0 = explode("/", $piecesMain[0]);
    for ($k = 0; $k < count($pieces0); $k++)
        {

        // echo $pieces0[$k]."\n";

        $compare[] = $pieces0[$k]; //заполняем его
        }
    }

for ($z = 1; $z < count($piecesMain); $z++)
    { //перебираем остальные элементы главного массива кроме первого
    $piecesZ = explode("/", $piecesMain[$z]);
    $result_array = array_intersect_assoc($compare, $piecesZ); //сравниваем их с первым элементом, выводим расхождение

    // echo $result_array."\n";

    for ($y = 0; $y < count($result_array); $y++)
        {
        echo $result_array[$y] . "/";//собираем каждый элемент главной строки (после сравнения)
        }

    echo "\n";
    }
```

на выходе

```
 /home/i/p/S/var/DR/IN/m/
 /home/i/p/S/var/DR/IN/m/
 /
```